# Multiple values in one column or not?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use comma-separated values in a DB Column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518566/when-to-use-comma-separated-values-in-a-db-column)

I want to create similar articles script. My idea is that articles would be similar by ID. For example if article have ID = 1 for this article, similar article will be with similar_id = 1

Table example:

```
ID     Similar_ID   
1          0
2          0
3          1
4          1
```

Article with ID 1, will have 2 extra articles with ID 3 and 4.

How to model table if there are more than similar ID ?

Example:

```
ID     Similar_ID   
1          0
2          0
3          1,2
4          1,2,3
```

Comment: ***NOT!***  It will make life hell for your successors.

Comment: _NOT_!!!!  Don't do it. You'll reget it eventually (I speak from experience early in my career)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use two tables, the original one you have above, and a separate one that has one row per Article-Similar Article.

So your original table would be: Articles

```
    ID     Content   
    1          bla 
    2          blah 
    3          etc.
    4          whatever
```

And your other table would be as you have above: ArticlesSimilar

```
    ID     Similar_ID   
    3          1
    3          2
    4          1
    4          2
    4          3
```

You would ensure that the combination ID-Similar_ID were UNIQUE.