# Very simple mysql join

Tags: mysql

Anyone could tell me how to connect these 2 tables. I tried do it myself.. but just wasted a time, i know it's easy but I somehow can't understand it. Table is from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920061/multiple-values-in-one-column-or-not/12920201#12920201)

```
Table Articles:

    ID     Content   
    1          bla 
    2          blah 
    3          etc.
    4          whatever

Table Similar:

    ID     Similar_ID   
    3          1
    3          2
    4          1
    4          2
    4          3
```

Comment: Connect them how? What result set are you trying to produce?

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.ID,a.Content,s.Similar_ID from 
Articles a inner join Similar s
on a.ID=s.ID
```

Comment: Its just joining 2 tables based on ID column and getting values.

Comment: Essentially, you are doing an inner join, selecting the row from table Articles and any rows from Similar that have the foreign key equivalent to the primary key in Articles. You are doing an INNER join, which means if the foreign key is null, it will return nothing.

Comment: yes.Its one type of many joins.based on the requirement you can decide which join to use

Comment: @AnandPhadke: so, go explain that in the answer. Also explain _why_ your answer is the answer to the question.

Comment: Its alredy explained above.pls check

Answer (score 0):

You want to browse the `Similar` table, and "convert" its IDs (e.g. 3) in `Content` (e.g. "Blah").

So:
     SELECT * FROM Similar;

will list all similarities. Since we have two `Ids` to convert (*something* is similar to *something else*), we need two separate JOINS with the same table `Articles`, and we'll alias them to "a" and "b":

```
 SELECT a.Content, b.Content
     FROM Similar
     JOIN    Articles AS a      ON (Similar.ID = a.ID)
     JOIN    Articles AS b      ON (Similar.Similar_ID = b.ID)
 ;
```

The first `JOIN` "decodes" the ID field of Similar, the second decodes "Similar_ID".

So

```
3     1
```

becomes now

```
Etc.  Blah
```

Or you can write:

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.Content, ' is similar to ', b.Content)
FROM... (same query as above)
```

and get

```
Etc. is similar to Blah
Blah is similar to whatever
...
```